# Конвертация данных из SQL-запроса в JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json, oracle, plsql

У меня есть таблица `table`, в которой есть данные.

Мне нужно написать запрос, так чтобы его результат возвращал мне данные в JSON формате, например, результатом:

```sql
SELECT column FROM table
```

было бы такое:

```
"\u053f\u0565\u0576\u057f\u0580\u0578\u0576"
```

Comment: Так MySQL или Oracle? и укажите версию...

Comment: oracle 11g у меня mysql тоже можно

Answer (score 2):

Я бы воспользовался Python + [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) + [SQLAlchemy](http://pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/) + адаптер (connector) для вашей БД.

Вот пример решения на Python для MySQL DB и Oracle DB ([cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# MySQL DB connection string
connection_string = 'mysql://user:password@server/dbname'

# Oracle DB connection string
import cx_Oracle
connection_string = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@tnsname')

# create SQL Alchemy connection object
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

# read rows from DB into Pandas DataFrame
sql_query = 'select * from my_table where <where clause>'
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, engine)

# export/write DataFrame to JSON file
df.to_json(r'd:/temp/db_export.json', orient='records', force_ascii=False)
```

Документация для используемых функций/методов:

- [sqlalchemy.create_engine()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html)
- [pd.read_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)
- [DataFrame.to_json()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: Интересно, откуда у Вас инсайд, что ТС интересуется решениями для Питона?

Comment: @Akina, да, это я погорячился...

Comment: @Akina, я тут подумал... а вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится...

Comment: Надеюсь, что так и будет.

Answer (score 1):

Для Oracle 11g можно сказать только одно: RTFM [Jena Adapter for Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25609/sem_jena.htm#RDFRM234)

Для MySQL - зависит от версии. Если это 5.7.8 или новее, то RTFM [The JSON Data Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) и [JSON Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html). Ну а если нет - то либо внешние средства, либо тупо работать с JSON как с обычным TEXT.